# Linux: Why doesn't ls -R *.zip find zip files down a tree?

Tags: linux

I've used DOS for 22 years but I'm new to Linux. So in Linux, when I execute

```
ls -R *.zip
```

Why do I receive:

> ls: *.zip: No such file or directory

When I'm at the top of a huge folder and file tree? Alternatively, how do I do

```
Dir /s *.zip
```

In Linux?

Comment: I hear that this is possible in the zeal shell (with similar syntax): ls \*\*/\*.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ls -R|grep .zip` or for full paths:

```
find .  -name '*.zip'
```

This will find any files ending in `.zip` in current directory and any subdirectories.

It seems a little longer but is much more powerful than the `dir /s *.zip` way of windows.

Comment: Okay - I getcha. I sometimes use dir /s/a/b|find /i "blah" which is conceptually the same.

Comment: Exactly; grep matches a string, or if you use "grep -E 'blah'" then you can use regular expressions in it

Answer (score 4):

To expand a bit further on the above answer, on Linux, the wildcards are expanded by the shell, which means that the shell will call the command with a list of matching file names as arguments.  And the shell only looks in the current directory for matching files (or in whatever directory you specify prior to the wildcard).  For example, a command such as:

```
ls *.zip
```

will actually translate into:

```
ls file1.zip file2.zip file3.zip
```

And, if there are no `.zip` files in the current directory, the literal file name `*.zip` gets passed to the command, in which case it doesn't fine a file called `*.zip`.  (A `*` is a legal character in a Unix/Linux file name, btw).  Now if you don't want the shell to expand the wildcards, but instead if you want the wildcard passed directly to the command you are calling, you will have to enclose it in quotes.  This has an interesting effect, in that a command such as:

```
find . -name *.zip
```

will give the expected results if you have no `.zip` files in your current directory (the find command sees `*.zip`).  But if you do have one or more  `.zip` files in the current directory, what gets executed is:

```
find . -name file1.zip file2.zip
```

which won't find any matches in any subdirectories (unless they happen to be named exactly `file1.zip` or `file2.zip`, etc).  So the moral of the story is, when using find, make sure to use quotes around any file name with wildcards.